# What is a simple splash screen code for corona?

Tags: coronasdk

Needing help on creating a simple splash screen using lua for Corona
Already tried a simple code and im lost like applesauce

Answer (score 5):

What do you mean by `splash screen using lua`? Do you want to add the iOS application splash screens  (launch images) to your project? Then just add the proper `.png` files inside your project folder where `main.lua` resides:

These images should adhere to the standard names and sizes listed below, and you do not need to specify them <strike>in the plist table or</strike> in the android table:

[image]

**Update**
 
**Note:** For iOS, you must specify launch image file names in the UILaunchImages table.

```
settings =
{
    iphone =
    {
        plist =
        {
            --icon image files table (see section above)
            CFBundleIconFiles = {
            },
            --launch image files table
            UILaunchImages = {
                {  -- iPhone 4 Portrait
                    ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "7.0",
                    ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default",
                    ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "Portrait",
                    ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{320, 480}"
                },
                {  -- iPhone 4 LandscapeLeft
                    ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "7.0",
                    ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default",
                    ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "LandscapeLeft",
                    ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{320, 480}"
                },
                {  -- iPhone 4 LandscapeRight
                    ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "7.0",
                    ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default",
                    ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "LandscapeRight",
                    ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{320, 480}"
                },
                {  -- iPhone 5 Portrait
                    ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "7.0",
                    ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-568h",
                    ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "Portrait",
                    ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{320, 568}"
                },
                {  -- iPhone 5 LandscapeLeft
                    ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "7.0",
                    ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-568h",
                    ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "LandscapeLeft",
                    ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{320, 568}"
                },
                {  -- iPhone 5 LandscapeRight
                    ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "7.0",
                    ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-568h",
                    ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "LandscapeRight",
                    ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{320, 568}"
                },
                {  -- iPad Portrait
                    ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "7.0",
                    ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-Portrait",
                    ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "Portrait",
                    ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{768, 1024}"
                },
                {  -- iPad LandscapeLeft
                    ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "7.0",
                    ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-Landscape",
                    ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "LandscapeLeft",
                    ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{768, 1024}"
                },
                {  -- iPad LandscapeRight
                    ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "7.0",
                    ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-Landscape",
                    ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "LandscapeRight",
                    ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{768, 1024}"
                },
                {  -- iPhone 6 Portrait
                    ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "8.0",
                    ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-667h",
                    ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "Portrait",
                    ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{375, 667}"
                },
                {  -- iPhone 6 LandscapeLeft
                    ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "8.0",
                    ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-667h",
                    ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "LandscapeLeft",
                    ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{375, 667}"
                },
                {  -- iPhone 6 LandscapeRight
                    ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "8.0",
                    ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-667h",
                    ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "LandscapeRight",
                    ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{375, 667}"
                },
                {  -- iPhone 6 Plus Portrait
                    ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "8.0",
                    ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-736h",
                    ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "Portrait",
                    ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{414, 736}"
                },
                {  -- iPhone 6 Plus LandscapeLeft
                    ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "8.0",
                    ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-Landscape-736h",
                    ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "LandscapeLeft",
                    ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{414, 736}"
                },
                {  -- iPhone 6 Plus LandscapeRight
                    ["UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion"] = "8.0",
                    ["UILaunchImageName"] = "Default-Landscape-736h",
                    ["UILaunchImageOrientation"] = "LandscapeRight",
                    ["UILaunchImageSize"] = "{414, 736}"
                },
            },
        }
    },
}
```

For more information, visit the `Launch Images` section from the following api: [Corona Project Build Settings](http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/distribution/buildSettings/index.html)

Keep Coding.................. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create your own splash screen that displays for a limited time, you can use a simple timer, and do something like this.

```
local background = display.newImage( "splash_background.png" )
timer.performWithDelay(1500, leaveScreen)
```

The leave screen function would contain whatever code you require to load the next scene. Here's my example if you are using the old director class.

```
local function leaveScreen()
    director:changeScene("Screen_Main")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Splash screen would be image or rectangle as per your choice. 
Ex: 
local background = display.newImage( "img.png" )/display.newRect(0,0,height,width)
background.x = centerX
background.y = centerY
group name:insert(background)

Answer (score 0):

I'm working right now on a project with lua and this is the code I'm using for my splash screen; it is a simple fade in - fade out splash. This is my "initiating" method(first one in the program)

whiteBag is the background image, a white png. 
logo is well, the logo. 
just before it ends, it calls an iniSetup method which throws the main menu in. It is mostly transitions.

```
function splashScreen()

whiteBag = display.newImage("images/backgrounds/white.png")

whiteBag.alpha = 0
whiteBag.x = display.contentCenterX
whiteBag.y = display.contentCenterY

logo = display.newImage("images/backgrounds/Logo-01.png")

logo.alpha = 0
logo.x = display.contentCenterX
logo.y = display.contentCenterY

transition.to(whiteBag, {transition = easing.inSine, time = 250, delay = 50, alpha = 1})
transition.to(whiteBag, {transition = easing.outSine, time = 250, delay = 900, alpha = 0})

transition.to(logo, {transition = easing.inSine, time = 500, delay = 50, alpha = 1})
transition.to(logo, {transition = easing.outSine, time = 500, delay = 900, alpha = 0, onComplete = mainMenuIn})

startIt = iniSetup()

end
```